# Configuration Cognos

Tags: configuration, ip, cognos, domain-name, datastage

Cognos worked perfectly. But for reasons, we changed the addressing plan of the network (IPs servers, domain name). 
So, cognos and datastage don't worked. I don't know how we change or modify  the domain name in cognos configuration.

Comment: did you look cognos configuration ?

Comment: What is the message?

Answer (score 0):

Cognos is wedbased tool. So, we configure server ip and domain name in cognos configuration. I think previously its configured correctly now you changed to another server but you not updated in cognos configuration,
Reference for cognos configuration as below 
[https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_10.1.1/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.10.1.1.doc/c_configuringcognos8.html][1]

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YFtW7F4QuY][1]